# map.fitBounds() with JSON data in a featureGroup

Tags: leaflet

I cannot get the fitBounds command to work on a project where I am bringing in data to a featureLayer using GeoJSON.

This:

```
map.fitBounds(pointsFeatureGroup.getBounds()); // Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid. at e.fitBounds (leaflet.js:5)
```

and this:

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(pointsFeatureGroup); // Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid. at e.fitBounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

don't work

My simplified code is here:
https://github.com/DPB61/leafletjs_problem2

If I just bring in markers individually into a normal Layer then a command like this works:

```
map.fitBounds(PointsLayer.getBounds());
```

but that raises other issues with other functionality for which a features layer is required.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is a classic asynchronous issue.

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

At the time you call `map.fitBounds(vesselsFeatureGroup.getBounds())`, the `vesselsFeatureGroup` is still empty (no child layer), therefore Leaflet cannot compute bounds.

Simply call the `getBounds` and `fitBounds` within the callback of your asynchronous task (`$.getJSON`)

Comment: Looks like I have a lot more study to do! Even after the 2nd read a lot of that went over my head. But I do see from your post what the cause of the problem is and study the info in the link to move further.